# Se gana en rendimiento usando {once: true} en lugar de removeEventListener?

Tags: javascript, events

Tengo una duda, acabo de aprende que puedo decirle a un evento de javascript que se ejecute una sola vez, y eso hace que no sea necesario escribir el removeEventListener.

Este era mi codigo

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  });
```

Y ahora es

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, {once: true});
  });
```

Quiero saber basicamente si tengo alguna ventaja en cuanto a rendimiento usando esta forma (para saber si vale la pena reemplazar el codigo en toda la aplicacion) y tambien me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para probar el rendimiento de estas cosas (esto es una pregunta un poco mas amplia, con que me recomienden algo para leer ya me sirve).

Comment: Sin hacer ninguna prueba te diría que no. Lo que si se gana es legibilidad en el código y ser explícito. Aún así yo no borraría la línea donde eliminas el listener, ya que puede no haberse ejecutado cuando se destruye el componente. Hay una opción en las devtools de Chrome dónde te muestra los event listeners activos, además de otras cosas, en la pestaña de performance.

Comment: Las preguntas sobre rendimiento en JavaScript son complicadas, porque dependen de la implementación del standard, además de existir varias implementaciones, cada una va cambiando, es decir que un "rendimiento" hoy podría ser distinto mañana. En la segunda opción el listener se elimina automáticamente luego de la primera llamada, así que yo la preferiría solo porque es mas corta.